# how to find "SA-181" record without using character "-" in mysql i.e only using "SA 181"

Tags: mysql

please provide the suggestion . 
 I am using following query to find data .

```
select * from material_1a where spec_no ="SA-181";
```

How can I find all records using

```
select * from material_1a where spec_no ="SA 181";
```

want to find without using "-"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid use `-` sign (or any other), you can use it's *ascii* value instead. For instance with a `CONCAT()`function:

```
SELECT * FROM material_1a 
WHERE spec_no = CONCAT("SA", 0x2D, "181"); /* equivalent to "SA"+"-"+"181" */
```

*Note: ascii code for `-` is 45 (decimal) or 2D (hex). See [ascii table](https://www.asciitable.com/)*

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions. In the example below the dot will be any character. So it will match `SA-181` or `SA 181` or `SA_181`.

```
select * from material_1a where spec_no REGEXP 'SA.181';
```

Comment: If you know then please tell me how to add this query in POJO of spring application. i have tried the your provided query but i am not getting record in my html page. (I have used the query in MySQL and it is working fine in it but i am facing problem within my html page)

Comment: If you are using Spring with JPA you can try native queries using `em.createNativeQuery("<SQL>")`. See: https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-native-queries/ . This should work with the provided query.